# Do Massachusetts residents pay tax on capital gains due to sale of foreign property?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, state-income-tax, massachusetts

I'm currently living in the US on a visa that allows me to file (federally) as a non-resident. However, since I have lived in Massachusetts all year, I am a resident of Massachusetts and must file as a resident.

If I sell an apartment in a foreign country, do I have to pay tax on capital gains in Massachusetts? (I'm assuming I don't have to do anything on my federal return about foreign property because I'm a nonresident.)

Comment: Are you sure you're a non-resident for federal tax purposes? The IRS uses different rules than immigration. It sounds like you probably *are* a US resident *for tax purposes* even though you're a non-resident by other definitions. You did refer to your visa type, so maybe you know about this and are exempt.  Just wanted to check. https://www.irs.gov/Individuals/International-Taxpayers/Substantial-Presence-Test

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I looked up the rules for my specific visa type. It makes me a non-resident for tax purposes for a fixed number of years.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you will need to pay capital gains tax in MA for that transaction. Here's how "[capital asset](http://www.mass.gov/dor/individuals/filing-and-payment-information/guide-to-personal-income-tax/massachusetts-income/capital-ordinary-gains-and-losses.html#CapitalAsset)" is defined in MA. It short, it follows the Federal definitions for most cases, including yours.

Note that MA follows the Federal rules with regards to the [Sec. 121 exclusion](http://www.mass.gov/dor/individuals/filing-and-payment-information/guide-to-personal-income-tax/massachusetts-income/capital-ordinary-gains-and-losses.html#Gain) (exclusion of gains on the sale of principal residence).