# Nonresident for federal taxes / Resident for MA taxes: Do I get taxed on worldwide income?

Tags: united-states, non-resident, state-income-tax, foreign-income, massachusetts

I am a nonresident alien for federal tax purposes in 2015 (due to the visa I'm on and the time I've spent in the US). But I am a resident of Massachusetts for tax purposes, since I've lived in MA for all of 2015.

My question is whether I get taxed on worldwide income in MA (and I assume I do not get taxed on worldwide income federally?)

In case it matters, I have a savings account in my home country (Canada) that has earned me around $500 of interest.

Comment: Related: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/55077/do-massachusetts-residents-pay-tax-on-capital-gains-due-to-sale-of-foreign-prope

Comment: @Brick: Thanks. It does seem related. I'm not sure if the answer is the same for property and interest income, but I would guess so.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is whether I get taxed on worldwide income in MA (and I assume I do not get taxed on worldwide income federally?)

Yes, MA taxes worldwide income of its residents. MA does recognize Federal tax treaties, though, so if you can apply treaty benefits to this income you can exclude it from MA taxes as well.